# How long would it take to bruteforce?

Tags: combinatorics, computational-complexity

I'm trying to reduce the solution space by excluding the wrong cases.

The original problem:
4851 choose 693 = 1.70E+862

Right now the possible combinations are (with n choose k):

1680 choose 420 = 4.36E+408

I'd attempt the bruteforce with a notebook, so it is not a powerhouse. I wonder if it is possible to find the solution now or should I try and reduce the available options further.

Update:
The problem is the following: I've got a set of graph nodes and some constraints. The goal is to connect the most nodes without violating the conditions.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: How many of the combinations are valid solutions? If it's just a few like $10^{100} $ among the $\approx 10^{400} $ then forget about brute force.

Comment: My current theory is that there will be only one valid solution.

Comment: What are the constraints?

Comment: Working with strongly regular graphs. So there are 3 conditions: the count of edges, neighbours and non neighbours.

Comment: What are those counts?  Is there a constraint on the number of nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How long would it take

Assume it takes 1 nano second to construct a candidate and to check whether it is the solution. Then divide the number of all candidates by $2.25 \cdot10^{27}$ to get the time it takes to check all of them, where the unit is *"age of the universe"*. Thus it takes around $$2 \cdot 10^{381} \text{ times the age of our universe}$$to brute-force check all possibilities.